# How to find pdf of $max|X_i|$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a population with pdf

$$f(x|\theta)=\frac{1}{2\theta}, -\theta<x<\theta,\theta>0$$.

I want to know the pdf of $max|X_i|$. How to find?

Comment: You work with the cdf. Find the probability that all of the $X_i's$ are less than a given $x$.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{P}(max |X_i| \leq x) =  \mathbb{P}( |X_1| \leq x,  |X_2| \leq x, \ldots,  |X_n| \leq x) = \mathbb{P}( -x \leq X_1 \leq x, -x \leq X_2 \leq x, \ldots,  -x \leq X_n \leq x) = \mathbb{P}( -x \leq X_1 \leq x )^n $ if assumed independence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @runr's Comment, $P(\max_i|X_i|\le x) = P(-x \le X_1\le x)^n = (x/\theta)^n.$ for $0 < x <\theta.$

For $n = 10, \theta=3,$ the following simulation in R illustrates the density
function.

```
set.seed(317)
n = 10;  th = 3
abs.max = replicate(10^5, max(abs(runif(n,-th,th))))
summary(abs.max)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.8256  2.6093  2.7973  2.7261  2.9139  3.0000 

hist(abs.max, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
 curve(10*x^9/3^10, 0, 3, add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I think it should be $0<x<\theta$